# Python class defined in the same file as another class - how do you get access to the one defined later in the file?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm very new to Python, I figure this question should be easy to answer.

My problem simplified is this...

I have 2 classes in a File class A and class B. Class A is defined first in the file and class B is defined second.

```
class A
    ...

class B
    ...
```

How do I get access to class B with class A?

```
class A
    something = B

class B
    somethingElse = A
```

Here is the actual code I'm trying to fix

```
class FirstResource(_ModelResource):
    class Meta(_Meta):
        queryset = First.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'first'
        allowed_methods = ['get','put']

        filtering = {
            'a': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'b': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'c': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }

        ordering = ['apt']

    # this is the line that would fix everything
    second = fields.ForeignKey(SecondResource, 'second', null=True, blank=True, default=None, full=True) 

    ...

 class SecondResource(_ModelResource):
    class Meta(_Meta):
        queryset = Second.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'second'
        execute_methods = ['get', 'post']
        filtering = {
            'name': ['exact'],
            'leader': ['exact'],
        }   

    super = fields.ForeignKey(FirstResource, 'super', null=True, blank=True, default=None, full=True)
    leader = fields.ForeignKey(FirstResource, 'leader', null=True, blank=True, default=None, full=True)

    ...
```

With no pre-declaring in Python I'm really not sure how to solve this problem. The First in models.py has a ForeignKey of Second, and Second has 2 Foreign keys of First.

Moving A below B does not solve the problem since B also needs A. I didn't write the code I'm simply trying to fix it - I need the 'second' foreign key back when I do a 'get' for the resource in both classes.

Comment: Moving class B above class A is not an option

Comment: Why?  Can you show us the actual code?

Comment: Edited so you can see more detail larsks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the answer was to use qoutes

```
B = fields.ForeignKey('api.resources.B', 'B')
```

Comment: Note that this functionality is specific to Django, and will not work in normal Python. This is because Django will search through its apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` for the correct package. So, this answer does not solve the simplified problem you asked.

Comment: can you please point out the part of django code that does it?

Answer (score 5):

To access `B`, you must first have defined `B`.

If you want to access `B` when you *define* `A`, you need to move it above `A` in the file.

If you want to access `B` when you *call methods in* `A`, you don't need to do anything: by the time you call a method of `A`, the interpreter has executed all the definitions.

Comment: So how do I force it to call a method before it returns with 'get'?

Answer (score 3):

When python finds a class declaration it creates a new scope and **executes** the code inside the class in this code block. This means that all class variables are instantiated when the class declaration is executed.

Now, if you have the two classes like:

```
class A:
    something = B

class B:
   pass
```

Python will execute `something = B` *before* creating the `B` class and thus it yields a `NameError`.

You can avoid this in a really simple manner:

```
class A:
    something = None

class B:
    pass

A.something = B
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that comes to my mind is to separate the classes into multiple files, so you could have a python package "models" in which you'll have A.py and B.py. Then you avoid the ordering issue

Answer (score -1):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print "In A"

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        a = A()
        print "In B"
b = B()
```

I think you want something like that.