# Using a class in the same python file

Tags: python, class

I have two classes in the same file.  I am trying to call ClassB from ClassB but receive the following error:

*NameError: name 'ClassB' is not defined*

```
class A:
    var = B();

class B:
    def foo(self):
```

Comment: Because that's a *class attribute* it's created when `A` is defined, at which time `B` hasn't yet been defined. Define `B` first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Class attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) (like `A.var` that you're trying to define) are evaluated when their class is parsed and created, so `B()` won't exist when you're trying to reference it in the definition of `class A`.

Fortunately, you can just add it afterwards and it will have the same effect:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    def foo(self): pass

A.var = B()
```

If appropriate, you could also define it as an instance attribute instead:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = B()

class B:
    def foo(self): pass
```

Answer (score 3):

The classes are "seen" in the order in which they are written. Therefore if you have a statement in the first class it will be evaluated directly, on the spot, before going any further in the file.

Your statement `var = B()` is therefore executed when class B does not exist yet for the Python interpreter.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. define the class B **before** the class A
2. OR put the statement `var = B()` **in the constructor of class A** as shown below

Your class A will look like this

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = B()
```

This means that the `self.var = B` will only be evaluated when you create your instance of the class A.

This topic has already been seen several times on Stack Overflow, I would suggest you take a look into one of them in the link below if you have any further questions.

[Python class defined in the same file as another class - how do you get access to the one defined later in the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13746683/4173886)

I have made a little program on repl.it to show you as an example if you want. It's [here](https://repl.it/HjVL/6).