# Python 3.x: class in file can't locate another class in the same file

Tags: python, class, oop, maya

I could use some help solving a NameError. It's worth noting that I'm executing this code within Autodesk Maya 2017.

Here is an outline of the problem: I cannot create an object of a class within the same file as the class I'm working in. So if I define a class foo() and a class foobar(), and in class foo() I try to create an object of class foobar() by entering foobarObj = foobar(), I get a nameError that states foobar is not defined.
Example code:

```
class foo:
    foobarObj = foobar # crashes here (nameError: foobar is not defined)
    __init__():
       pass
class foobar:
    fooObj = foo # crashes here as well
    __init__():
       pass
```

It's entirely possible I don't understand something about OOP in python and that my mistake is evident in that example code. I'm not sure if I need to define foobar before foo? If so, how can I make the code work? I need to create an object of the first class in the second class, but also an object of the second class within the first (this could be the problem, because python doesn't know the second class has yet been defined when I attempt to create an object from it in the first class?).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746683/python-class-defined-in-the-same-file-as-another-class-how-do-you-get-access-t) seems to address a similar if not the same issue, but I don't really understand what is going on in it or the answers provided because it is rather specific to Django.

However, if the example code I provided seems 'kosher', here is more information and the actual code I'm running:

There are three files in my actual project, createUI.py which calls a function to create a new window, suite_modules.py which contains methods for the program's UI, and bb_modules.py which contains two classes with UI methods and basic command methods. The error occurs in the bb_modules.py file when I attempt to create an object of the UI class within the basic commands class.

createUI.py  # this is the first script executed, and it imports the second script suite_modules

```
# createUI.py #
import os
import maya.cmds as cmds

# store the user's script directory as variable 'usd'
usd = cmds.internalVar(usd=True)

# prep the import path
bb_modules = 'suite_modules'
bb_modules = os.path.join(usd, bb_modules)
# import the module
import suite_modules
reload (suite_modules)

# create a new window
def createFloatingWin():
    UI = suite_modules.SuiteUIcommands()
    UI.createBuddySuiteUIWindow()
```

suite_modules.py # this is the module imported by the first script. It imports a third module called bb_modules.py

```
# suite_modules.py #
### Imports and script properties ###
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os
class SuiteUIcommands():
# Imports
# store the user's script directory as variable 'usd'
usd = cmds.internalVar(usd=True)
# Prep the file path for bb_modules
bb_modules = 'bb_modules'
bb_modules = os.path.join(usd, bb_modules)

# Import batch buddy commands
import bb_modules
reload (bb_modules)
# there is more to the script but it is not relevant, 
# the execution crashes during this import
```

bb_modules.py # this is where the execution crashes, during the import from suite_modules

```
# bb_modules.py #
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os
import maya.mel as mel

class BBbatchCommands:
    # Define Variables
    # Get the UIcommands
    BBUI = BBUIcommands() # THE CRASH HAPPENS HERE #

    def __init__(self):
        self.uselessVariable = 0

    # there is more to the class but it never gets that far

class BBUIcommands:
    # Import the other module in this file, the batch commands
    BBcmd = BBbatchCommands() # THE CRASH HAPPENS HERE IF 
    # THE CLASSES ARE DEFINED IN REVERSE

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # as usual, there is more to the class but it isn't relevant
```

And finally here is the full stack trace output by Maya:

```
# Error: line 1: name 'BBUIcommands' is not defined
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
#   File 
"C:/Users/censored/Documents/maya/2017/scripts\BuddySuite.py", line 21, in <module>
#     import suite_modules
#   File 
"C:/Users/censored/Documents/maya/2017/scripts\suite_modules.py", line 22, in <module>
#     class SuiteUIcommands():
#   File 
"C:/Users/censored/Documents/maya/2017/scripts\suite_modules.py", line 31, in SuiteUIcommands
#     import bb_modules
#   File 
"C:/Users/censored/Documents/maya/2017/scripts\bb_modules.py", line 13, in <module>
#     class BBbatchCommands:
#   File 
"C:/Users/censored/Documents/maya/2017/scripts\bb_modules.py", line 16, in BBbatchCommands
#     BBUI = BBUIcommands()
# NameError: name 'BBUIcommands' is not defined #`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Comment: The order of the `class` declarations matter. How could the `foo` class know what `foobar` is, if `foobar` has not yet been declared?

Comment: But really your design is broken. Why do they both need instances of the other? And why do they need to be at class level? At the very least, only one should need a reference to the other. Alternatively, define both instances at module level, then they can both access them.

Comment: As an aside -- if this is running in Maya 2017 it's Python 2.7.x , not 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the top level Python code *and* also the *class bodies* are executed sequentially when the module is first imported. Referring to any name that is not yet defined will raise a `NameError`

One simple solution would be to postpone the assignment:

```
class BBbatchCommands:
    def __init__(self):
        self.uselessVariable = 0

class BBUIcommands:
    BBcmd = BBbatchCommands()

BBbatchCommands.BBUI = BBUIcommands()
```

No crash!

However, the code still smells odd, this kind of circular dependency doesn't look right to me.

Comment: This solution requires defining the BBUI variable within the class as so: "BBUI = None", correct? So the solution is to create an empty variable, then fill it with the object AFTER I define both classes?

Comment: @DesignRunner no need for `BBUI = None` though you can put it there if you want. Python object and class attributes and variables can be added at any time anywhere.

Comment: The circular dependency exists because they are both different "modules", and functions within one class need access to functions contained in the other class "module". Basically, this started out as a non-OOP project, and has recently been reformatted to use classes. When I designed the methods/functions initially, I didn't plan for them being in classes and so when I made the classes, I've had to take a rather silly approach to making the flow still work. I'm aware this isn't best practice and will avoid it in the future, but I still needed this specifric design to work.

Comment: Antti Haapala: wow, I didn't know that, python is always blowing my mind. Thanks for the help folks! It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside a `class` is actually a module in python behind the scenes, so it's actually executed when the script is parsed just as if you did an import.

When defining variables in the class body you are defining a static variable that will be shared between all the instances of the class. This is perfectly fine as long as we get the behaviour we are looking for. Classes as simple name spaces for variables alone is pretty normal as well.

To illustrate the difference:

Static variables:

```
class Batch:
    commands = []

a = Batch()
b = Batch()
a.commands.append("a")
b.commands.append("b")
print(a.commands)
print(b.commands)
```

Will print:

```
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b']
```

Instance variables:

```
class Batch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.commands = []

a = Batch()
b = Batch()
a.commands.append("a")
b.commands.append("b")
print(a.commands)
print(b.commands)
```

Will print:

```
['a']
['b']
```

If you are making several instances of your `BBbatchCommands` class, I would worry.

Everything set in `__init__()` is unique to the instance.